# Standard Enthalpy of Formation

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

I have hard time understanding why in the definition of standard enthalpy of formation (SEF), the reactants and the products are required to have fixed temperature and pressure. Specifically, LibreTexts define SEF as follows: "SEF is defined as the change in enthalpy when one mole of a substance in the standard state (1 atm of pressure and 298K) is formed from its pure elements under the same conditions" ([link here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Valley_City_State_University/Chem_121/Chapter_7%3A_Thermochemistry/7.4%3A_Standard_Enthalpy_of_Formation)).

My question is the following: consider the case where we want to get 1 mole of O, given 1/2 mole of O_2. So, we start with a container with 1/2 moles of $O_2$ in 1atm, 298K. Then, we add heat to break the covalent bonds. Suppose we managed to have only isolated O atoms in our gas. However, the temperature and possibly the pressure are higher than the desired values (1atm, 298K). By adjusting the volume and the temperature, we can then reach the desired values. So now, ideally, we have 1 mole of isolated O atoms in 1atm, 298K. However, this is an unstable configuration, so we will not achieve it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: SEF does not say what path is to be taken to get from elements at STD conditions to the compound at STD conditions, as it does not depend on the path. It may have many formal and real steps.

Comment: Please explain : What is your question, Plemath ?

Comment: My question: how is it possible to end up with 1 mole of isolated oxygen atoms in 1atm, 298K? Such a configuration is unstable, and O_2 molecules will start forming.

Comment: Look in your table of SEF's.  Does it give a value for water vapor at 1 atm and 298 K?  How is this possible?  The answer to your question is the same as the answer to this question.